# @react-native-community/datetimepicker Button text color on the Android calendar is white making it invisible

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, android-calendar, react-native-calendars

I need a calendar in my project, but the buttons on it are invisible. I have tried reinstalling it and other things like changing the style.xml in the calendars android folder nothing works...

```
import DateTimePicker from "@react-native-community/datetimepicker";
```

```
{
  showCalendar && (
    <DateTimePicker
      testID="dateTimePicker"
      value={date}
      mode={"date"}
      is24Hour={false}
      display="calendar"
      onChange={setDateHandler}
    />
  );
}
```

There isn't much code that I could've written wrong, the showCalendar state and setDateHandler work, so I've excluded them.
Here are some maybe relevant things from package.json:

`"@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^5.0.1", "expo": "~43.0.2", "react-native": "0.64.3",`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which buttons you are talking about? 
1. Used to open calendar?
2. Select date?
3. Ok/Cancel?

Comment: @Akshay My bad I forgot to add pictures... 
[pic1](https://ibb.co/1RcPg0j)
[pic2](https://ibb.co/f0LVBYp)
[pic3](https://ibb.co/FJSs4bN)

The Ok Cancel buttons are the problem

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that the `display` prop was set to `display="calendar"`, when it should've been set to `display="default"`.
Thanks to @Akshay for answering quickly.

Comment: Good to hear that you have got expected results. Even you can change default header, selected date and buttons colours. If you need that, let me know.